# Association Issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models User, Club and Mcq.

In club model. I assign club (class) as -

1. 9-physics
2. 9-chemistry
3. 10-physics
4. 10-chemistry...

Here is my Association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mcqs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Mcq < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :club
end
```

In my student view (student show index) I show all club (as subject) and after click on a subject I just want to show Mcq topic of that related subject.

for that my Club Controller is -

```
class ClubsController < ApplicationController

#its show subject list
def student_show_index
    @club = current_user.clubs
  end

  #its show topic according to subject.
  def student_show_topic
    @club = current_user.clubs
    @mcq = @club.first.mcqs.order('created_at DESC')
  end

end
```

So my question is, when I click on subject physics it show all the Mcq of 9th. and same for chemistry.

I just want to filtered Mcq according to subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a `params` as `club_id` in the link of subject which you are clicking. eg. `<%=link_to "Subject", x_path(club_id: n) %>` Then you can catch this params in your controller action as `params[:club_id]`. then rewrite the controller action as following

```
def student_show_topic
  @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  @mcq = @club.mcqs.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Not you may need to permit `club_id` this params in your controller, if not yet added. Hope this will help you. Let me know if any issues?

Comment: wow. wonderful Its working and so helpful for me. bcoz I'm new on RoR. I just get a back button issue. I will manage it. thank you so much.

Comment: After Apply for a MCQ assessment, I move to Mcq controller. n there I show questions of mcq, in that page I have a link of back button <%= link_to "Back", student_show_topic_club_path(@club), :class => "button" %> but after click on that link I get error - Couldn't find Club with 'id'=#<Club::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f320cfff1a0> [WHERE `clubs_users`.`user_id` = ?]
Extracted source (around line #80):
       def student_show_topic
 80   @club = current_user.clubs.find(params[:id])
    @mcq = @club.mcqs.order('created_at DESC')
  end

Comment: Not very clear form this comments section, but seems the problem in `@club = current_user.clubs.find(params[:id])` this statement, try rewrite this as `@club = current_user.clubs.where(id: params[:id]).first`  or `@club = Club.where("id =? AND user_id=?", params[:id], current_user.id).first`

Comment: I write '@club = current_user.clubs.where(id: params[:id]).first' in def apply of Mcq controller. then get error - **
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Mcqs#apply
**    'No route matches {:action=>"student_show_index", :controller=>"clubs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]'